# ActiveRecord::Relation with inner join of latest record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models: Website and Status in one to many relation.
 I would like to list in my view latest status of each website and list websites by status decreasing.

Simple `@websites = Website.joins(:statuses)` won't help in this scenario.

I wonder how can I get relation of all websites with joined column status which will be equal to latest status of this website.

As I figured out each object in that relation should look like:

```
<Website id: 5, domain_url: "http://example.com", created_at: "2015-10-15 10:52:35", updated_at: "2015-10-15 10:52:35", status: 200>
```

With that result I would be able to list statuses in view without additional SQL queries in loop. 

EDIT:
I'm using mySQL as database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question, you have a situation where a `Website` has many `Status` objects and you are looking to see what just the last one is.

I don't know that you can easily do this in Arel as the

If you are using Postgresql, you can tweak the SQL to make this work using a [window](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tutorial-window.html) and the [first_value](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) functionality.

You can see a working example of this query here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9a845/1

in `ActiveRecord` you could make it happen with:

```
Website.
  joins(:statuses).
  select(<<-SQL)
    distinct on(websites.id) websites.*, 
    first_value(status) over (partition by website_id 
      order by statuses.created_at desc) status
  SQL
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using MySQL